# Bazaar and $Id$

Tags: svn, version-control, bazaar

Most my sources are in subversion and I use '$Id$' to add revision information to those sources. Then I can easily check what sources were used (e.g.. --version option shows that info).

Now I'm going to use bazaar and I can't find such a functionality.
Is there any equivalent of svn '$Id$' in bazaar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having automatically generated Id tags that show a sensible version number is impossible to do with DSCM tools like Bazaar because everybody’s line of development can be different from all others. So somebody could refer to version “1.41” of a file but your version “1.41” of that file is different.

Basically, $Id$ does not make any sense with Bazaar, Git, and other distributed source code management tools.