# Add a global variable to static lib for versioning?

Tags: c++, c

This question related to [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638207/how-to-store-a-version-number-in-a-static-library).
The answer states that you can add the version as a char somewhere in the library code.

```
char* library_version = { "Version: 1.3.6" };
```

If I was following the approach for an executable, I would just place this somewhere in the beginning of main. Where should it be placed in a library to be sure it will be executed?

Comment: It's a symbol that holds a string. It's not a function. You don't execute a string.

Comment: Just note that if you do this, the `library_version` should be a rather unique name as to not clash with other libraries. e.g. `libfoo_version`

Answer (score 1):

In the same place than other global variables declaration.
Please notice this is a variable declaration, this is not an instruction, it will never be executed. What can be executed is a function returning this variable or comparing it with an other

Comment: So it would be in some `global-include.h` header file?

Comment: Yes by example, or it can be in an other include file of the lib

Comment: No, that's not a good idea, with out `static` you'll have multiple definition error, and with `static` you duplicate the string each time you include it somewhere. Just put it in a source file, any source file that have access to global name space.

Comment: @user3528438: Certainly it should be in a source file... but why are you singling out "some" files that would not have access to the global namespace? All files can access it.