# How to alias 'git checkout' to 'git co'

Tags: git, alias, git-alias

I'd like the command `git co` to be the same as typing `git checkout`.

A normal Bash alias (`alias co='checkout'`) doesn't work.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

The command:

`git config --global alias.co checkout`

will create a git alias to do that.  It will add the following entry into your global `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    co = checkout
```

Comment: Find more details (and examples) in the manual here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Answer (score 22):

Also, can edit this into your git config:

```
[alias]
   co = checkout
```

Comment: You don't need to do '!git'.  You can just use 'co = checkout'.  That prevents re-invoking git under another process... which can be advantageous on Windows where starting a new process is expensive.

Comment: for people who don't know where is git config:  vi ~/.gitconfig  or  git config --global -e

Answer (score 0):

simply to add some comments, the bash alias is for setting alias for a command, and the co or checkout is the parameter or flag to the command git, so it won't work.