# How to auto-generate a version string in git

Tags: linux, git, version-control, auto-generate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable ident string for Git repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792838/enable-ident-string-for-git-repos)

In my project, every source file (regardless of the language - Java, Python, shell) has a comment line that contains source control information - branch, date of last commit, committer name, etc.

This is done by using special placeholders (e.g. $Branch$) which are auto-replaced by the source control application.

Is it possible to achieve similar functionality in git?

I am using Git Extensions on Windows and yet-to-be-decided GUI on Linux, but I assume both are just GUIs that invoke the git command-line tools.

Comment: see questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792838/enable-ident-string-for-git-repos and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384108/moving-from-cvs-to-git-id-equivalent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to read about [smudge/clean filters](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) in Git in order to get some iteration of keyword-replacement.

Grok section "Keyword Expansion", where example of expanding $DATE$ keyword explained (and **a must** reverse-operation). In you case most work of expanding $SOMEKEYWORD$ to version string can be performed by `git describe` under the hood, clean part must be implemented by hand (*your* hand)

Answer (score 5):

Git does not have support for these placeholders and probably never will have.

Instead, automaticaly generate source file which contains output of `git describe` command and include it while compiling your application. Or you can generate some configuration file instead (JSON or whatever you want).

To generate C++ header with version info, use shell script like this (you can add these commands directly to your makefile):

```
(
  echo '/* Generated file, do not edit. */'
  echo  '#define APP_VERSION "'`git describe`'"'
  echo  '#define APP_VERSION_DATE "'`git log -n 1 --format=%ai`'"'
) > version.h
```

To do this for scripting languages you can use post-commit and other hooks.

Comment: -1 – not true, git has support for placeholders, see the other answer.

Comment: Calling that "support for placeholders" is a bit of a stretch. +1 just to counter the IMHO overtly exuberant downvote.