# how to embed DVCS revision information when building without it

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, cmake, software-distribution

In my build system, every time I run a new build I save revision and hash information of the current commit in a few variables, and use them in my sources without issues. For example the window title is formatted like "NAME-REVISION-HASH".

The only problem of this is that sometimes people build the project by downloading the standard sources that do not contain commit information and thus the revision and hash is all 0ed.

What can be done to prevent this? Adding a separate file that contains this kind of information defies the advantages of using distributed version control system because it would need to be manually updated at every commit...

Is there a way to allow people without dvcs to get the right revision and hash information?

Comment: Just make cloning the repo _the_ way to acquire the source. It is reasonable to expect that developers who wish to be able to build your project use the same version control system as you. Think about how all of those public code hosting sites work (Google Code, github, bitbucket, Codeplex, etc.).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving from CVS to git: $Id:$ equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384108/moving-from-cvs-to-git-id-equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

> Adding a separate file that contains this kind of information defies the advantages of using distributed version control system

WTF? "people build the project by downloading the standard sources..." because they have not any VCS, one more file "defies" nothing

> because it would need to be manually updated at every commit

And what? Auto-committed file with specially-prepared keywords (or text constants) is not a big problem, at least for Mercurial

Comment: Yes but that file would change every time a commit is done and would pollute the commit list of file with that additional information...

Comment: @koda - yes, but it's fair price (IMNSHO): you can't get "all for nothing". But I (personally) like Ry4an's idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git describe` to get a unique string, that you can then include in your build. `git` itself does this to set it version (`git version` here returns `git version 1.8.2.rc1.19.g443d803`, i.e., 1.8.2-rc1 + 19 commits, latest commit has SHA1 443d803e0dacd0a1c6700503689f3cd95751aba1; `git describe` returns `v1.8.2-rc1-19-g443d803`).

From the SCCS days comes the custom of expanding `$Id:$` and other keyword constructions, which made perfect sense in those days when the VCS just handled individual files; that is vestigial today (and `git` doesn't do any "keyword expansion" at all).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mercurial to generate the archives it's already handled for you.  The `hg archive` command, which powers the web UI tarball / zip downloads automatically includes a `.hg_archival.txt` file which looks like:

```
repo: 0339f7b37c3416248e4e0b183a481aa40ade150e
node: 0339f7b37c3416248e4e0b183a481aa40ade150e
branch: default
latesttag: null
latesttagdistance: 1
```

So your code can use logic that first checks for the local repo to get the version info and if that's not there then looks for the `.hg_archival.txt` file.  The `latesttag` and `latesttagdistance` are especially handy if you're tagging releases.  You can use them to build up a version string that's useful for both humans and DVCSs like:

```
2.0.1-5-40ade150e
```

which could be read as "five commits since version 2.0.1 with the hash of 40ade150e"

Comment: Just note - if you want to follow "Semantic Versioning" (not a bad idea), "changesets after" must be separated with "+". `2.0.1+5-40ade150e`

Answer (score 0):

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5022854/32043):

> By now there is support for $Id:$ in Git. To enable it for file
>   *README* you would put "README ident" into *.gitattributes*. Wildcards on file names are supported. See [man gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for details.