# Proper comment codes for GIT version control?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, commit

I didn't know how to properly ask the question and for that I apologize.

Basically I want to know how can I set up eclipse to recognize the version of the project I am working on and how many revisions etc.

I had this working on CVS but for some reason on GIT I can't get it to work.

On CVS I had this block of comment code

```
/*
 * ${file_name}
 *
 * Version:
 * $$Id$$
 * Revisions:
 * $$Log$$
 */
```

And of course it would display the file name, version and revision. With GIT it does nothing...

I googled as much as I could and found no answer, hopefully one of you guys can help me out. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384108/moving-from-cvs-to-git-id-equivalent

Comment: thank you for that link @FredericHenri, I'll check and see if it solves my issue

Comment: Well I might go back to CVS, apparently according to many user comments on that page GIT has no intention in supporting this

Comment: If you **really want** keywords, move to SVN|Mercurial, not rollback to CVS

Comment: Read also http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[git]%20smudge%20clean here