# Bazaar: Modify file content before commit via hook?

Tags: python, bazaar, bazaar-plugins

I'm switching from SVN to Bzr for my private projects. There is one feature missing for me, which SVN provides: The replacement of a $Id:$ placeholder with the latest version identification. So far, Bzr provides hooks to do some tricks within the commit process. I've managed to get a list of modified files an manipulate them on the local disk. The problem I encounter is that the snapshot, which is taken from the files that are part of the commit, is made before my modification. The result is, that I have a change of my files, but only local.

The workflow I want to build is:

- Call Bzr commit
- modify the $Id:$ macro
- tell bzr that this modified set is
  the changeset
- let Bzr do the rest of it's work

Any ideas?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/bazaar-and-id

Comment: @NicDumZ: yes it is a duplicate. Can you mark it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this extension: http://launchpad.net/bzr-keywords